# Parameter in HttpPost edit action is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

When clicking save to submit my form, my HTTPPost Edit Action receives a null value for `IEnumerable<MedicalProduct> productList`.  I am not sure what parameter to use for my edit Action to prevent nulls.  I would try and determine the cause with some breakpoints but cannot find the spot before the parameter is assigned null.

**Side Note:**

I am adapting my code to use this new Model/ViewModel hierarchy.  My Controller hasn't been completely tested with these new models, but I started testing the Edit Action, and received the null reference exception when trying to use the parameter `IEnumerable<MedicalProduct> productList` in my Edit post action.

**Another Side Note:**

I am using a sub-ViewModel class `MedicalProductViewModelLineItem` (haven't figured out a better name yet) inside my ViewModel `MedicalProductViewModel` because I need a way to retrieve all the Brand names from the database with one database call, and then assign them one by one to the `MedicalProductViewModelLineItem`.

***EDIT: CODE UPDATE 10/22/13 5:14pm CST***.  The values produced in `FormCollection.Keys` parameter in the HttpPost `Edit` action method are now fixed.  Now, values like "Products[0].Name" or "Products[0].ID" are produced in `FormCollection.Keys` parameter instead of "p.Name" or "Name".  ***However***, the `productList` parameter is still `null`.

---

## Model Classes

---

### MedicalProductViewModel

```
public class MedicalProductViewModel
{
    public List<MedicalProductViewModelLineItem> Products { get; private set; }

    //public SelectListItem BrandSelectListItem { get; private set; }

    public void BuildViewModel(IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModelLineItem> productsList, IEnumerable<Brand> brandList)
    {
        BuildProducts(productsList, brandList);
    }

    public void BuildViewModel(IEnumerable<MedicalProduct> productsList, IEnumerable<Brand> brandList)
    {
        BuildProducts(productsList, brandList);
    }
    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BuildSelectListItems(IEnumerable<Brand> brandList)
    {              
        return brandList.Select(b => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = b.Name,
            Value = b.ID.ToString()
        });
    }

    private void BuildProducts(IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModelLineItem> productList, IEnumerable<Brand> brandList)
    {
        var medicalProducts = productList.Select(p => new MedicalProduct()
        {
            BrandID = p.BrandID,
            ID = p.ID,
            Name = p.Name,
            Price = p.Price
        });

        BuildProducts(medicalProducts, brandList);
    }

    private void BuildProducts(IEnumerable<MedicalProduct> productsList, IEnumerable<Brand> brandList)
    {
        Products = productsList.Select(p => new MedicalProductViewModelLineItem()
        {
            BrandID = p.BrandID,
            BrandName = brandList.Single(b => b.ID == p.BrandID).Name,
            BrandSelectListItem = BuildSelectListItems(brandList),
            ID = p.ID,
            Name = p.Name,
            Price = p.Price
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

### MedicalProductViewModelLineItem

```
// Sub-ViewModel of MedicalProductViewModel
// It gets displayed as one row on a view.
public class MedicalProductViewModelLineItem 
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    // is a foreign key
    public int BrandID { get; set; }

    public string BrandName { get; set; }
}
```

### MedicalProduct

```
// DOMAIN MODEL
public class MedicalProduct 
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    // is a foreign key
    public int BrandID { get; set; }
}
```

---

## Controller

---

### MedicalProductController

```
public class MedicalProductController : Controller
{
    private MvcMedicalStoreDb _db = new MvcMedicalStoreDb()

    //
    // GET: /MedicalSupply/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        MedicalProduct product = _db.Products.Find(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        var productList = new List<MedicalProduct> { product }; 
        var viewModel = GetMedicalProductViewModel(productList);
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    // ==========================================
    // NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION OCCURS IN THIS ACTION
    // ==========================================
    // POST: /MedicalSupply/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModelLineItem> productList, FormCollection values)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var product in productList)
                _db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        var productViewModelList = GetMedicalProductViewModel(productList);

        return View(productViewModelList);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

---

## Views

---

### Edit.cshtml

```
@model MvcMedicalStore.Models.MedicalProductViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>MedicalProduct</legend>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count(); i++)
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Products[i])        
        }
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

### EditorTemplates\MedicalProductViewModelLineItem.cshtml

```
@model MvcMedicalStore.Models.MedicalProductViewModelLineItem


@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.ID)

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(item => Model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(item => Model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.Name)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(item => Model.Price)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(item => Model.Price)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.Price)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(item => Model.BrandID)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(item => Model.BrandID, Model.BrandSelectListItem)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.BrandID)
</div>
```

### EDIT: (Pictures obsolete)

two images of the `foreach` approach, and `for` approach used in MedicalProductViewModel.cshtml, and the resulting key values of `FormsCollection` parameter `values`

[image: Using the for approach]
[image: Using the foreach approach]

Comment: Add a FormCollection parameter to your HttpPost Edit Action like this: `public ActionResult Edit(IEnumerable<MedicalProduct> productList, FormCollection values)`, and let me know what key/value pairs are posted to your controller.

Comment: @ataravati After Enumerating the IEnumerable of ResultsView of values, i get numbered indices 0 to 4 with values: "_RequestVerificationToken", "ID", "Name", "Price", "BrandID"

Comment: What if you replace `IEnumberable<MedicalProduct>` in your HttpPost Edit Action with `IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModelLineItem>`?

Comment: @ataravati `productList` is still `null`.

Comment: So, your keys are "ID", "Name",..., and not something like "Product[0].ID", "Product[0].Name",...?

Comment: @ataravati That's weird, I just expanded the results again for values, and now the indices show "p.ID", "p.Name", "p.Price", "p.BrandID". I don't know what caused it to be different. Anyhow, is that useful information?

Comment: You mean they don't even have indexes, like p[0].Name, p[0].Price,...? That's strange.

Comment: @ataravati Yes, when I use the `foreach` approach, I get "p.Name", when I use the `for` approach, I get "Name" etc.

Comment: That is impossible. Please pay more attention. Didn't you say before that you get numbered indices too?

Comment: @ataravati I've added two pictures to my question, one showing the values of FormCollection when using the foreach approach, and one using the for approach.  When I said I got numbered indices 0 to 4, I was referring to the numbered indices of `AllKeys`, like Key[0], Key[1], etc., from the FormCollection values.  See picture.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately, I'm very busy now. I can't spend enough time looking into your issue. I just noticed that your IEnumerable properties in your ViewModel have private set accessors. That could be part of the problem. Also, your ViewModels should be simple POCO classes, instead of populating the properties in a Constructor, do it in your Controller.

Comment: @ataravati I understand, In the days since, I've updated my code above. Now the FormCollection values are showing "Products[0].ID", "Products[0].Name" etc. However, the productsList parameter is still null. Please let me know if this helps single out a particular solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `BindAttribute` with `Prefix` in your Controller Action like below:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Prefix = "Products")] IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModelLineItem> productList)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var product in productList)
            _db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    var productViewModelList = GetMedicalProductViewModel(productList);

    return View(productViewModelList);
}
```

Comment: Your Model is in a partial view that is rendered in a foreach loop with `EditorFor(m => m.Products[i])`. That adds a `Products` prefix to the FormCollection keys posted from the partial view to your Controller. You need to tell the model binder that it needs to use the  keys with `Products` prefix to bind your model.

Answer (score 0):

Change your view from foreach loop to for loop

```
@foreach (MvcMedicalStore.Models.MedicalProductViewModelLineItem p in Model.Products)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(item => p.ID)
   //rest of the code.
}

to 

@for ( i = 0;  i < Model.count(); i++)
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].Name)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Name)
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].Price)
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Price)
   //rest of the code.
}

[HttpPost]
 public MedicalProductViewModel GetMedicalProductViewModel(ICollection<MedicalProduct> productList)
    {
        var brandList = _db.Brands.ToArray();

        var mapper = new MedicalProductMapper();

        return mapper.MapMedicalProductViewModel(productList, brandList);            
    }
```

Make it more explicit, specify

> FormMethod.Post

`@using (Html.BeginForm()) { }` to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "forId" }))
    {}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it did not change my results.  I had an out of range exception which I corrected by changing `<=` to `<`.  Also, count is not a method of Model.  I changed that to `Model.Products.Count()`, `Html.Hidden` would not accept `Model[i]`, because IEnumerable doesn't accept indexes, so I used `Html.Hidden(Model.Products.ElementAt(i).ID)` and it still failed)  So I used `HTML.HiddenFor(item => Model.Products.ElementAt(i).ID)` and this gave me the same null results for my parameter `productList`

Comment: `m => m[i].ID` doesn't work because .net doesn't allow indexing to be applied to an expression of that type.  In order to get the Count of MedicalProducts, it doesn't need to be called from `Model`, it has to be called from `Model.Products`.  I don't know why [HttpPost] has been applied to my MedicalProductViewModel function, it's not an action method.

Comment: Please declare your model in view @model ienumerable<type> and then you can use the index and regarding httppost you are right it should be won't action method

Comment: declaring `ienumerable<type>` as the model won't help in this case because only one `type` is passed to the view, and that contains an ienumerable member of type `MedicalProductViewModelLineItem`